# sqlでphp artisan migrate でMigration table created successfullyと出ているのに反映されていない

Tags: php, mysql

**行いたいこと**
テーブルsnowsの追加

**問題**
php artisan migrate でMigration table created successfullyと出ているのに反映されていない

**試したこと**
・envファイルの確認
・mamp再起動
・migrateファイルの再作成

[image: ターミナル画面][image: phpmyAdimn]

Comment: 作成したmigrateファイルの中身は何が記述していますか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

メソッド定義に定義づけしたら出来ました。
コメント等ありがとうございます。